# compile rc file in VS 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I am reading about resource file in C++. It is mentioned about we can compile to generate data structure to be used in application.

I request help in writing simeple rc file in VS2010 and compile and what it produces output and how we can use in application.

It would be if helped with VS 2010 and VC++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you understand what [a resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7.aspx) is used for. This is how you add icons, bitmaps, sounds, strings, and other *localizable* resources to your Windows application. The Windows SDK comes with a resource compiler, rc.exe. It can be invoked automatically as part of a Visual Studio build. It works on the resource files in your project, which will generally have the ".rc" extension. They are essentially just scripts, listing all of the resources to be linked into the executable.

Creating an new Win32 Application project using the built-in template will give you a good example on how this works. And of course you can add a new resource file to an existing project by right-clicking on the project folder in the Solution Explorer, clicking "Add New Item", and selecting "Resource File (.rc)". Once you've got a resource file, use the "Resource View" toolbox window to add items to it.